# wxPython adding list to grid with while loop

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to input a list to a grid and whenever I run it I get this error: SetValue(): invalid row or column index in wxGridStringTable. I apologise if it's something simple as I've only started learning python recently.

Code:

```
import wx
import wx.grid

class main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        items = ["milk", "cherries", "soup"]
        total = len(items)
        grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)
        grid.SetRowLabelSize(0)
        grid.SetColLabelSize(0)
        grid.CreateGrid(total, 1)
        listItem = 0
        while listItem < total:
            grid.SetCellValue(listItem + 1, 1, items[listItem])
            listItem += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = main()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is trying to set the values starting at row 1, col 1 but the  rows and cols are zero based.
Also instead of using a while loop, its better to use a for loop with enumerate to get the index of the item.

```
import wx
import wx.grid

class main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        items = ["milk", "cherries", "soup"]
        total = len(items)
        grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)
        grid.SetRowLabelSize(0)
        grid.SetColLabelSize(0)
        grid.CreateGrid(total, 1)
        for index, value in enumerate(items):
            grid.SetCellValue(index, 0, value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = main()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```